# Starting new Kafka Streams microservice, when there is data retention period on input topics

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, apache-kafka-streams, event-sourcing

Lets assume i have (somewhat) high velocity input topic - for example *sensor.temperature* and it has retention period of 1 day.
Multiple microservices are already consuming data from it. I am also backing up events in historical event store.

Now (as a simplified example) I have new requirement - calculating maximum all time temperature per sensor.
This is fitting very well with Kafka Streams, so I have prepared new microservice that creates KTable aggregating temperature (with max) grouped per sensor.
Simply deploying this microservice would be enough if input topic had infinite retention, but now maximum would be not all-time, as is our requirement.

I feel this could be common scenario but somehow I was not able to find satisfying solution on the internet.

Maybe I am missing something, but my ideas how to make it work do not feel great:

1. Replay all past events into the input topic *sensor.temperature*. This is large amount of data and it would cause all subscribing microservices to run excessive computation, which is most likely not acceptable.
2. Create duplicate of input topic for my microservice: *sensor.temperature.local*, where I would always copy all events and then further process(aggregate) them from this local topic.
   This way I can freely replay historical events into local topic without affecting other microservices.
   However this local duplicate would be required for all Kafka Streams microservices, and if input topic is high velocity this could be too much duplication.
3. Maybe there some way to modify KTables more directly, so one could query the historical event store for max value per sensor and put it in the KTable once?
   But what if streams topology is more complex? It would require orchestrating consistent state in all microsevice's KTables, rather than simply replaying events.

How to design the solution?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The aggregated maximum would be all-time, per the data you have available in a topic. The KTable doesn't delete data once the input topic retention is reached. If you need to query historical data, then yeah, just re-produce that one record into the input topic and let the table update itself

Comment: @OneCricketeer: The problem is that I do not have all required data in the topic -  when microservice is deployed for the first time a lot of data is far gone because of retention policy (last 1 day). That gives me partial maximum in KTable. 
As I understand your suggestion: replay to original input topic (so it will affect other microservices) but make "smart" replay - choose only required max event per sensor.
This will work in this scenario above. But what if I really need to read all events - for example to calculate all-time average?

Comment: In an ideal world, you'd have an event that can be interpreted as "as of such-and-such time (in event time terms), the average was" and you'd have a heterogeneous event stream.  In a more generalized (i.e. one that does not equate a stream with a Kafka topic) stream framework, that's pretty straightforward, but in Kafka Streams, you're running up against the limitations of the framework around the permanence and weight of a stream.

Comment: I was not saying replay the world, I was saying to only query out the previous maximum. There's no need to re-consume everything on the Kafka side when there's better distributed BI/SQL tools that can find maxes much faster

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would create a topic that stores the max periodically (so that it won't fell off the topic beacuse of a cleanup). Then you could make your service report the max of the max-topic and the max of the measurement-topic.

Comment: This is exactly what the statestore of the KTable would already be doing